# For Eclipse-Mars.2 CDT, is there a difference between Launch and Run. if so what is it?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse Mars.2 with CDT. I am having trouble specifying build/run/debug configurations. Now i see a Launch configuration as well. For Eclipse-Mars.2 CDT, is there a difference between Launch and Run. If so what is the difference? Thanks.